# PStricks not show the lines in Xelatex (Texwork)

Tags: graphics, pstricks, texworks

[image: This is my configuration]

I can't see the lines, only the positions of words.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[PointSymbol=none](4,6)
    \pstGeonode[PointName={V,none},PosAngle=-135,CurveType=polygon,linecolor=red]{A}(4,0){B}(4,6){C}
    \pstMarkAngle[arrows=->,MarkAngleRadius=4]{B}{A}{C}{$\theta$}
    \pcline[offset=-8pt,linecolor=red]{|*-|*}(A)(B)\ncput*{1}
    \ncline[linestyle=none]{A}{C}\naput[nrot=:U]{$\sec \theta$}
    \ncline[linestyle=none]{C}{B}\naput[nrot=:U]{$\tan \theta$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: X]

Comment: Show the log file ...

Comment: @user187802 i see this in the compiling: "MiKTeX GPL Ghostscript 9.25: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1"... IDK where is the log file.

Comment: No problem here with fully updated TeX Live 2020 and gs 9.50.

Comment: @Libreik: The logfile is in the documents directory.

Comment: @user187802 i think found it, but has nothing there.

Comment: @Libreik: What do you mean by "nothing there"?

Comment: Same error message with MiKTeX and gs 9.25, but the image is correct. Do you have the `--shell-escape` switch for the compiler?

Comment: @user187802 i see a document of text in white.

Comment: @Bernard already now i did it, but continue equal.

Comment: @Bernard: --shell-escape is not needed

Comment: @Libreik: The logfile has a lot of informations and will be created with _every_ xelatex run!

Comment: @Bernard , right, but i back to the start

Comment: @user187802 this are all the documents that builded the compiling [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1H9fp6FAQ8GTwwi9gdx-QS3IrDJauGvnJ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: What if you compile from the command line (no texify, just xelatex)?

Comment: @Bernard how i do it? ....well i did it , already now

Comment: And what happened?

Comment: @Libreik: Evverything is fine with your example with TeXLive and GhostScript 9.53. Can you update MikTeX?

Comment: @Bernard i see the finish this:  **Output written on a.pdf (1 page).
Transcript written on a.log.** , but I continue without find the a.log, and the pdf continue equal.

Comment: @user187802 you want to say reinstall whole MikTex?

Comment: @Libreik: No! _Update_ not reinstall. The MikTeX comnsole has an option for a simple update.

Comment: *A priori*, the .log file is in the same directory as the .tex file, or in a subdirectory.

Comment: @user187802 i can see the a.log , is it [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aDnbJC4vgItUf4uQBylov1ustXnvlgmK/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @Bernard i can get the a.log file , but with TexMaker.

Comment: @user187802 yes, but not appear nothing for update.

Comment: Your log say that everything is up to date. It looks like a problem with xdvipdfmx.

Comment: I've just tested with TeXworks under Win 7, after I deleted all auxiliary files and the ouput pdf obtained with my usual editor, and the .log file is in the .tex file directory, with the same error message as you, but nevertheless a .pdf output. This being said, in the toolbar od TeXworks, you can select the simple xelatex compiler.

Comment: @Bernard yex, i has see that the option  simple Xelatex yes build the a.log and a.aux, but with XeLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX not. Despite that I still have the same pdf output

Comment: @user187802 thx, but that is solvable?

Comment: @user187802  i execute in the terminal "xdvipdfmx" and get " xdvipdfmx:security risk: running with elevated privileges", ¿yes work?

Comment: As a workaround, you could compile your pstricks code in an independent file, and use the result with a simple `\includegraphics{…}`.

Comment: @Bernard thx, I didn't want to find that solution, but anyway. What program do you recommend?

Comment: There seems to be a problem with MiKTeX ghostscript or xdvipdfmx Let's hope it will be solved in the near future. If you can't compile it the code as an autonomous file with xelatex, use the standard way  `latex -> dvips -> pstopdf`.

Comment: @Bernard ,this can be done with TexWork?

Comment: On checking, I discover the composition menu doesn't have a `latex` item, but TeXmaker has

Comment: @Libreik: I can reproduce the GhostScript error message in my virtual WIN7 machine, but still get a correct output with xelatex. Try the follwoing: Open a command window, go into the test documents directory, run `xelatex --no-pdf test.tex` which creates a file `test.xdv`. Now run `xdvipdfmx -dNOSAFER test.xdv`. which creates a `test.pdf`. Are the lines still missing? If yes, what does the output of the `xdvipdfmx` run say?  For `test` use your own file name.

Comment: @Libreik: By the way: Which PDF-viewer are you using?

Comment: @user187802 im using the predeterminate of TextWork (in MikText ).

Comment: What happens if you view the generated PDF with the Adobe Reader? Are the lines also missing?

Comment: @user187802 yes, nothing diference.

Comment: If you are willing to install anydesk, then I can solve the problem online. send private EMail for more informations: hvoss@tug.org

Comment: Libreik and @user187802 Can you let me know here, in a comment, when I can clean up the comments? It's just many so the system signals to start deleting for cleaning. If you are ready (or maybe delete the older part of comments here yourself you both read and it's just past). Thanks and good luck!

Comment: @StefanKottwitz yes, you can start to delete ..thanks. xD

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on macOS, when running xelatex on a tex file containing `pstricks` drawing. I use macTeX and have ghostscript 9.52 installed by homebrew.

The following comment under question [MacTeX Ghostscript permission issue on macOS 10.15 Catalina](https://discourse.brew.sh/t/mactex-ghostscript-permission-issue-on-macos-10-15-catalina/6086/5) posted on Homebrew Community Discussion helps me.

> It looks like `gs` uses `-dSAFER` as default from 9.50. Using the `-dNOSAFER` flag solved the issue for me.

This is what I do:

- Open (user) config file of `(x)dvipdfmx`.

  - On TeX Live, you can get its full path by running `kpsewhich -progname=dvipdfmx -format='other text files' dvipdfmx.cfg`.
  - On MiKTeX, `dvipdfmx.cfg` is located in `texmf\dvipdfm\config`, from the file list of [MiKTeX package `miktex-dvipdfmx`](https://miktex.org/packages/miktex-dvipdfmx/files).
- Open `dvipdfmx.cfg`, find the line starting with `D  "rungs -q -dNOPAUSE`, insert  `-dNOSAFER` just after `-q`, save with permission.

The above workaround works for xelatex only, and a better place to add `-dNOSAFER` or [`--permit-file-read`](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.50/Use.htm#Safer) would be the wrapper `rungs` provided by TeX Live. (I don't know if MiKTeX has a similar wrapper.)

Comment: ...not work for me.

Comment: @Libreik Hmmm. Perhaps you can open an issue under https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/.